# Is it possible to move a logic brick/re-order the logic stack?

Tags: game-engine, workflow, logic-bricks

I have a fair number of logic bricks on one specific object, but recently had to add a condition to a very early part of the logic stack. This makes the trace cross almost all of the other traces and makes it look extremely cluttered. Is there some way to move it up above some of the logic bricks? Basically I want to be able to change the logic stack order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimize the logic brick (the down pointing arrow in the top left corner), then click on the up or down arrows to move it through the stack.

[image: logic brick]

Comment: That is cumbersome . . . but works. Thanks. Any idea how to do it without minimizing? I hate chasing the logic brick around with my cursor :P Or any info or thoughts on implementing it? Drag and Drop would be handy!

Comment: As far as I know that is the only way to reorder the bricks. Looking in to possibly scripting a solution.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise nope, you need to minimize it and move it one step at a time. - I usually just leave it a mess.

Comment: lol, I guess that is one solution . . . **#OCDHell**

Comment: I suggest to close the bricks anyway. Collapsed bricks look much more organized then expanded once.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "Repeat Last" listed at User Preferences » Input » Screen » Screen (Global) check what keyboard shortcut it's bound to. It can zip an individual brick around incredibly quickly (after you've explicitly moved the brick once with its up/down arrow). I dare say it could make the difference between a complex project being editable or not.

I noticed, however, that "Repeat Last" is completely deleteable in my Blender 2.78a, which suggests I inserted it myself somehow, I don't remember. The exact syntax inside the entry is just "screen.repeat_last" to create it from scratch.

To impress girls, a double-speed variant can be created by assigning separate "Repeat Last" entries to the press / release phases of your chosen key. This terrifying configuration can storm through 43 bricks in about 3 seconds (tested) and should probably be banned! Happy days.

Comment: I never thought to use the `Shift`+`R` command in that way, great tip!